# Filter result of sql table based on input flask

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, flask

I have table from sql and i need to make filter on it when click 'search' button filter result based on 'Name' Column.

.py:

```
@flask.route('/next_lecture')
def nextlec():
    check = (session['isadmin'])
    check_id = session['Id']
    if check == 1:
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `sessioncreate` WHERE `ownerId` = %s ORDER BY Id DESC;', str(check_id))
        myresult = cursor.fetchall()
        # get info
        return render_template("next-lecture.html", myresult=myresult)
```

.html page:

```
<table class="table table-striped mb-0" id="search" name="search">
    <thead>
        <tr class="live-blue text-white">
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">STime</th>
            <th scope="col">ERime</th>
            <th scope="col">Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in myresult %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[6]}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Table Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0bC5.png)

How can i achieve that?

Comment: what is the problem? Did you test it?

Comment: @baderman I need to filter result based on input

Comment: and you do it by `WHERE ownerId = %s` isnt it?

Comment: @balderman No you don't understand my question. Open attached picture please, i need when i type for example 'rr' in search input field and click search button return only row that contains 'name = rr' just like that

Comment: what is the problem, make a input in html , send the it to flask,  access it and using request.args or request.form then run the query which `SELECT * FROM 'sessioncreate' WHERE 'name' = %s ORDER BY Id DESC;', searchvariable `